# How to respect spaces and line breaks in solr OR How to delete \ n and \ t code in solr

Tags: solr, nosql, solrj

I am using the version of sol 8.4, and for indexing I use the DHL (data import handler) since the main source of my data is postgresql.
I have a field called desc_croquis which is a string, the format is already established from the database, example:

```
                                       DESCRIPCION:
A  PARTIR DEL SEGUNDO  ANILLO DE LA CIUDAD DE AGUASCALIENTES Y LA CARRETERA A SAN LUIS PO-
TOSI RECORRER 7.4 KM PARA TOMAR LA DESVIACION A CALVILLITO, CONTINUAR  2.5 KM HASTA EL JAR-
DIN DE NINOS DE  CALVILLITO, SEGUIR POR 1.2 KM SOBRE LA TERRACERIA A LA TINAJA PARA LLEGAR
A LA DESVIACION A LA IZQUIERDA QUE LLEVA AL RETONO. AVANZAR 1.1 KM HASTA UNA DESVIACION DE
BRECHA,  DONDE HAY UN  ALAMBRADO (AL ESTE). CONTINUAR  POR 300 M PARA ENCONTRAR UNA FINCA,
SEGUIR 100 M POR  BRECHA HASTA DONDE TERMINA EL ALAMBRADO. CRUZAR POR PARCELA AL ESTE UNOS
200 M HASTA DONDE COMIENZA  OTRA PARCELA  ALAMBRADA. TOMAR AL SUR POR 500 M JUNTO AL ALAM-
BRADO HASTA LLEGAR AL VERTICE 01001004.
LA MARCA  CONSISTE EN UNA PLACA  DE ALUMINIO DE 9 CM DE DIAMETRO CON LA INSCRIPCION "INEGI
01001004 22-06-93". LA PLACA SE ENCUENTRA EMPOTRADA EN UN MONUMENTO DE CONCRETO NO VISIBLE
DE 40x40x60 CM.
```

So as it is with its spaces and line breaks is how my system uses it, so I need it in solr.
but it is not like that, when the json returns I get the following:

```
 "desc_croquis":"DESCRIPCION:\nA PARTIR DEL TERCER ANILLO (AV. SIGLO XXI) DE LA CIUDAD DE  AGUASCALIENTES  Y SOBRE LA CA-\nRRETERA FEDERAL No. 45 RECORRER 12.7 KM HASTA EL ENTRONQUE A SAN BARTOLO EN DIRECCION ESTE\nCONTINUAR SOBRE EL ENTRONQUE POR 1.2 KM, PASAR LA LOCALIDAD  COTORINA Y A LA ALTURA DE LOS\nULTIMOS  TOPES TOMAR CON RUMBO SUR POR CAMINO DE BRECHA. SEGUIR  POR 800  M Y JUNTO  A UNA\nCERCA DE ALAMBRE  SE UBICA EL VERTICE 01001002.\nLA MARCA CONSISTE EN  UNA PLACA DE  ALUMINIO DE 9 CM DE DIAMETRO CON LA INSCRIPCION \"INEGI\n01001002 12/01/93\". LA MARCA SE ENCUENTRA EMPOTRADA EN MONUMENTO DE CONCRETO NO VISIBLE\nDE 40X40X60 CM.\n\n"
```

As shown, it **returns** **"\n"** every time there is a line break and a **"\t"** every time there are spaces.

I want to disapper these "\n" and "\t"

The weird thing is that when I change the output **wt=xml** if it respects the spaces as in the database, here the output in xml:

```
<result name="response" numFound="85126" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="descripcion">Estación Geodésica Horizontal</str>
    <str name="tipo">100</str>
    <int name="gid">100004</int>
    <str name="desc_croquis">DESCRIPCION:
A PARTIR DEL TERCER ANILLO (AV. SIGLO XXI) DE LA CIUDAD DE  AGUASCALIENTES  Y SOBRE LA CA-
RRETERA FEDERAL No. 45 RECORRER 12.7 KM HASTA EL ENTRONQUE A SAN BARTOLO EN DIRECCION ESTE
CONTINUAR SOBRE EL ENTRONQUE POR 1.2 KM, PASAR LA LOCALIDAD  COTORINA Y A LA ALTURA DE LOS
ULTIMOS  TOPES TOMAR CON RUMBO SUR POR CAMINO DE BRECHA. SEGUIR  POR 800  M Y JUNTO  A UNA
CERCA DE ALAMBRE  SE UBICA EL VERTICE 01001002.
LA MARCA CONSISTE EN  UNA PLACA DE  ALUMINIO DE 9 CM DE DIAMETRO CON LA INSCRIPCION "INEGI
01001002 12/01/93". LA MARCA SE ENCUENTRA EMPOTRADA EN MONUMENTO DE CONCRETO NO VISIBLE
DE 40X40X60 CM.

</str>
    <str name="lugar">COTORINA</str>
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be encoded in JSON. When you decode the JSON content in your application, it will be decoded as an actual newline and tab character.

Comment: You should handle these things at index time.